# SQL SELECT FROM Two

Tags: sql

**TABLE1**

```
ID    |     DATE  
 a    |   10-06-2012    |   
 b    |   07-07-2012    |   
 c    |   10-06-2012    |
```

**TABLE2**

```
ID    |  COST  |  
 a    |   3    |  
 b    |   4    |  
 c    |   4    |
```

I have two tables and I would like to search the `DATE` e.g. `10-06-2012` and return the total `COST` for that `DATE` being 7.

ID is common in both tables.

Comment: This is not difficult. Pick up a book on SQL and read it. [Try something.](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

Join the tables, and use the `sum` aggregate to add the values:

```
select sum(t2.COST)
from TABLE1 as t1
inner join TABLE2 as t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
where t1.DATE = '10-06-2012'
```

Comment: Thank You, I have been stuck for hours .